# Media player play song on top of another song

Tags: java, android-studio

Something is wrong with my media player......When i click on a song, it plays it.....But when I click on another song, it plays it on top of the other song that was already playing. How do I fix that?

code:

```
public void playSong() {
    if (PlayingScreen_List != null){
        uri = Uri.parse(PlayingScreen_List.get(position).getPath());
    }
    try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, uri);
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (mediaPlayer != null || mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),uri);
    }else{
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),uri);
    }
    mediaPlayer.start();
}
```